# Set with Custom String Class Problem

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, set

I have written a custom string class.
I want to use STL set with it. I have overloaded operator <
But still its giving me problem

```
error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const     String' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>    could be 'String &String::operator =(const String &)'
1>           'String &String::operator =(const char *)'
1>          'String &String::operator =(const wchar_t *)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const String, const String)'
```

I guess, It is asking for overloaded operator= (const String , const String)

But its impossible to create such an overloaded function

My String class is this

```
String ();
String (const char * pStr);
String (const long int pData);
String (const double  pData);
String (const int pData);
String (const wchar_t * pStr);
//Copy Constructors
String (const String& rhs);
String (const String& rhs, const int pStartIndex, const int pNumChar);

//Overloaded Operators
String & operator= (const String & rhs);
String & operator= (const char * rhs);

String & operator= (const wchar_t * rhs);
String   operator+ (const String& rhs);
//String &  operator+= (const char ch);
String & operator+= (const String& rhs);
friend bool operator== (const String& lhs, const String& rhs);

friend bool operator< (const String& lhs, const String& rhs) {

    return strcmp(lhs.vStr, rhs.vStr);
}

friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& ostr, String& rhs);

char & operator[] (int pIndex);
char   operator[] (int pIndex) const;

const char * String::Buffer () const;
wchar_t * GetTChar();

int String::GetLength () const;

~String ();
```

Comment: Please add some minimal, but complete, code that demonstrates the problem. The actual problem that you are having could be unrelated to what you think it is.

Comment: My first guess is that you are trying to make a `set<String const>` rather than a `set<String>`, but it is hard to tell without having more information.

Comment: No i am using `set<String> var;`   ,   no i am not trying to print the String

Comment: The error is probably a red herring. Can you show us your `String` class? (And explain why you're not using `std::string`)

Comment: We are using custom String class because we were told to do so

Comment: @Sumit: Code, as has been specifically stated a handful of times now. Your mere promise that you've implemented everything right is not sufficient; you're here in the first place because something is _not_ right. And "told" by whom? God?

Comment: hey, did you find the solutions??

Comment: @Sumit: Did you feel like bothering to answer my questions yet? Downvoting because OP is completely ignoring all comments and [the basic premise of the code is sound](http://codepad.org/bQe6nWuO).

Comment: I answered all your comments, i told you why i cant use std::string and I edited my question to include the string class.

Answer (score 0):

"no operator found which takes a **left**-hand operand of type '**const** String'"

it seem you have an expression like

```
a=b;
```

where both `a` and `b` are `const String`.

You cannot assign to a const (although the compiler looks desperately seeking for an implementation of such an assignment)

Comment: yes thats what i cannot understand, its impossible to create opeartor= with two constant arguments

Comment: @Sumit: You are most likely misusing `std::set` somewhere which causes the compiler to require such an impossible overload, e.g trying to assign to a value in set. The String class itself may be OK.

Comment: @Sumit: yes, you cannot create that operator, but the compiler is somewhere required to use it. The problem is not String, but something you did with it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well I can only answer the question you've posed with the information you've given, and the answer is that [**this works for me**](http://codepad.org/PHSLepx8).